# Getting a single list from a 2D list in Python 3.x?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

Having some difficulty here. My goal is to read numbers from a column in a gameboard and print these numbers out as a specific list. I don't have much experience with lists and neither do I grasp the concept properly so I'm having some difficulty with getting them to work. So far, all I could muster was this:

```
def getColumn ():
    for i in range (0, 9):
        row = datalist[i]
        column = row[x]
        column.append[i]
```

Doesn't seem to work properly, could anyone point out why? I would really appreciate it!

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: x is not defined anywhere ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a version that tweaks your original code:

```
datalist = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]
]

def getColumn(col_num, data):
    column = []
    for i in range (0, len(data)):
        row = data[i]
        column.append(row[col_num])
    return column
```

Which gives:

```
getColumn(1, datalist)
Out[9]: [2, 5, 8]
```

Some problems with your original code:

- You didn't have any way to tell `getColumn` which column you wanted- you need to make this an argument of your function
- `getColumn` relied on there being a global variable called `datalist`. Passing the data as an argument is safer.
- `datalist` had to have exactly nine rows, or you'd get errors or wouldn't get the full column returned.

Comment: The point was to create a program that would solve a sudoku puzzle. For this, we created a board and put some sample values in there. Now the goal is to get values from the columns of that gameboard and make a single list from it. This will be then used later on to solve the puzzle.

Comment: OK, so it's probably safe to assume that your data will have 9 rows if it's a sudoku solver, but I think the other comments I made still apply. Do you understand the rest of the answer, or is there still something you're unclear on?

Comment: Does make more sense to me, still unclear about a few things. What does "len(data)" do?

Comment: It gives the number of rows. The length of a list is the number of objects in it, and the objects in `datalist` are the lists representing each row.

Comment: Ah, okay now that makes sense. Makes it a lot simpler for me. Thanks a lot Marius! Really appreciate it

Answer (score 7):

try doing something like this to just use builtins

```
rows = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

cols = zip(*rows)

print cols[0]  #column 0 ....
```

or better use numpy

```
import numpy as np

my_board = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
np_ar   = np.array(my_board)

print np_ar[:,2]  #print column 2 ..
```

Answer (score 2):

would this work?

```
col = 1
column1 = [row[col] for row in datalist]
```